# EditText replaces the last character in a line with a dot automatically

Tags: android, android-edittext

I've noticed a strange behavior of EditText.
There was an update for sure that caused it.

The steps are:

1) Put the cursor at the end of a line whose last character isn't a dot

2) Press space key

3) The last character is replaced with a dot

So if there is a text like:

```
How are you
I'm fine. Thank you
```

And I put the cursor at the end of the line

```
How are you
```

And press space key. The line becomes:

```
How are yo.
```

I use Android 7. It looks like a bug to me. I would understand appending a dot, but not replacing a character with it.
If it's a feature, please, advise me how to deactivate it.

I also noticed that it doesn't always happen. But when it happens it's annoying.

Comment: is it on double space key ?

Comment: @Ashish I also facing this issue with double space. What is the cause ?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya if it's problem with you're double space then go to **keyboard setting** -> **Text Correction** -> there will be **Double-Space full stop** off that option then it will be working properly with you. This type of question needs to be asked on [android forum](https://android.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Ashish I didn't notice that I had to press space 2 times. One time is enough. The main condition is - the cursor is placed right after the last character in line.

Comment: you can close the question cause people will downvote you. Thank you for replying

Answer (score -1):

You should either make it with marquee effect using :

```
 android:ellipsize="marquee" 
 android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
```

or you can use multiple lines for the text view:

```
android:maxLines="4"
```